# iPhone: Question about touch events for map views

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I have a mapView which has a couple of mapAnnotations. Id like to record the event when the user touches on a mapAnnoatation and then Id like to capture the information from that particular annotation and save it.
I came up with the following code to get started. But I do not see any output on my console after I build and run and the tap on an annotation on my device.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view     calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
LocationMapAnnotation *tempAnnotation = view.annotation;
NSLog(@"The tapped annotation was %@", tempAnnotation.title);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can remember, that particular method will only be called when an accessory view on an Annotation's callout view is tapped; so, for example, if you tap the blue icon in this screenshot:

[image: MKAnnotation callout]

By implementing the method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

you should hopefully be able to achieve what you're after.

Comment: wow how did you get the accessory button onto your annotation. I would like to do that as well. Woud you happen to have any sample code to do this? Thanks

Comment: @user657514 You're very welcome! To add an accessory, you can use either the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` property or the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` on an MKAnnotation (the property requires a UIView and Apple says it should be 32 pixels or less in height). For sample code, try [this from Apple's reference library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746).